# How can I get more info on open pipes show in /proc in Linux?

Tags: linux, pipe

In Linux if you go digging in `/proc/<pid>/fd` often you'll see output like:

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 30 15:14 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 30 15:14 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 30 15:14 10 -> pipe:[90222668]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jul 30 15:14 11 -> pipe:[90222669]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 30 15:14 13 -> pipe:[90225058]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jul 30 15:14 14 -> pipe:[90225059]
```

How do I get more info about the open pipes, such as which process is on the other end?

Comment: lsof, of finding in whole `/proc` is slow. Can someone provide a more effective solution?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Similiar to other answers, but:

```
lsof | grep 90222668
```

Will show you both ends, because both ends share the 'pipe number'.

Comment: Ah, of course. Works as expected. You can even tell the file descriptor number and which end is the reader and which is the writer by looking at the 4th column of output!

Comment: I think that number might be the inode number of the pipe for pipefs which you can't mount.  I am looking for a way to get inode to filename mappings, but this might be the best way.  By the way, I love this question :-)

Comment: Somehow this is not working for me. All it outputs is the pipe itself.

Comment: running lsof as standard user may not give you information from all processes. Usually you don't have permission to see all processes' /proc/<pid>/fd directory as a non-root user.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `lsof -n -P | grep 90222668` to avoid unnecessary name lookups, which should speed it up.

Comment: for looking up with name of FIFO the following can be done. lsof -n | grep FIFO_NAME

Answer (score 5):

The only way to find what process is on the other end is by looping over all processes in /proc and seeing which are using that pipe (ie, which have symlinks in /proc/pid/fd to the same pipe ID)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. One way to automate this is: `ls -l /proc/*/fd/ | grep $PIPE_ID; ls -l /proc/*/fd/$FD | grep $PIPE_ID`  The first ls command will print the file descriptors of both ends of the pipe, while the second will give you the process id

Answer (score 2):

The most information I know how to get on open pipes is

```
lsof|grep FIFO
```

Still only tells about one end of it, I'm afraid.

Comment: That's about the same as I can divine from /proc, I assume lsof gets it from the same location.

Answer (score 2):

```
lsof +E | grep FIFO | grep 90222668
```